# Stack safety of scalaz StreamT's flatMap

Tags: scala, scalaz

The following code constructs a stream as a tree of streams flattened by `flatMap`. The problem is that it is not stack safe when iterating over the resulting stream. What would be a stack safe equivalent of this code?

```
import scalaz.Id._
import scalaz.StreamT

object StreamOverflow extends App {

  def streams(branchingFactor: Int, depth: Int): StreamT[Id, Int] = {
    if(depth == 0) {
      StreamT.empty
    } else {
      StreamT.fromIterable(1 to branchingFactor) flatMap { _ =>
        streams(branchingFactor, depth-1) }
    }
  }

  streams(10, 10) foreach { _ =>  } // stack overflow
}
```

I am using scalaz 7.2.0-RC1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Trampoline` instead of `Id`:

```
import scalaz.Id.Id
import scalaz.{ StreamT, ~> }
import scalaz.Free.Trampoline
import scalaz.syntax.applicative._

object trampolineId extends (Id ~> Trampoline) {
  def apply[A](i: A): Trampoline[A] = i.point[Trampoline]
}

def streams(branchingFactor: Int, depth: Int): StreamT[Trampoline, Int] =
  if (depth == 0) StreamT.empty else {
    StreamT.fromIterable(1 to branchingFactor).trans(trampolineId).flatMap { _ =>
      streams(branchingFactor, depth - 1)
    }
  }
```

Now something like `streams(10, 10).foreach(_ => ().point[Trampoline]).run` might run for a very, very long time, but it shouldn't overflow the stack.

Comment: Thanks! I thought stack safety would be somehow built into `StreamT`. I will add that I can then hide the `Trampoline` by `def hideTrampoline[A](stream: StreamT[Trampoline, A]): StreamT[Id, A] = StreamT.unfold[A, StreamT[Trampoline, A]](stream){ _.uncons.run }` and stack safety is preserved.